# Angular access image src attribute

Tags: angular

how can I access image `[src]` attribute from function in controller?

```html
<ion-slides pager>
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let image of uploadService.downloadURLs">
         <img [src]="image" class="slide-image" />
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have the uploadService.downloadURLs in the component.ts, you should be able to get it.

Otherwise you can do with **`(click) = getImage(image)`**